# SQL Server - Select if one of all columns are unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to select if one row where multiple columns are the same.  For example:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4

  a    b    1   2
  b    b    1   2
  a    c    1   2
  b    b    1   3
  a    c    2   1
```

*Condition: Select only if values of columns (col1, col2, col3) are different from other rows and value of col4 is max of rows which are the same.*

For example expected Output is:

```
  a    b    1   2
  b    b    1   3
  a    c    1   2
  a    c    2   1
```

Comment: SQL queries become increasingly possible when you actually try to write them.  That being said, have you tried answering this question yet yourself?

Comment: you have two answers because it is not clear what you mean when you say col4 is max.  max of what?  col3 and col4?  other matching rows?  something else?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've tried with distinct and it got no point

Comment: @Hogan I couldn't get your point, guys. value for col4 is integer so if there is multiple same rows, It will return row have max value for col4

Comment: @HungNguyen it would be nice if you [accept the most appropriate answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @HungNguyen -- ok I edit the question the make the english clearer and less ambiguous.  This is just a group by with one column being max() -- very simple sql operation

Comment: @HungNguyen If one of the answers you've got have solved your problem (and from what I see, they should both get the same result, so both of them should solve it), you should mark it as accepted so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mandatory `NOT EXISTS` solution... your condition written as a not exist query:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (col1 varchar(100), col2 varchar(100), col3 int, col4 int);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('a', 'b', 1, 2),
('a', 'c', 1, 2),
('a', 'c', 2, 1),
('b', 'b', 1, 2),
('b', 'b', 1, 3);

SELECT *
FROM @t AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM @t AS dup
    WHERE dup.col1 = t.col1
    AND   dup.col2 = t.col2
    AND   dup.col3 = t.col3
    AND   dup.col4 > t.col4 -- outer row has smaller col4
)
```

[**Demo on DB Fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e6b7e101d8e80a855898eb4522dacbdc)

Answer (score 4):

*Yes possible, just use `group by` with `max` aggregation as*

```
with tab(col1,col2,col3,col4) as
(
  select 'a','b',1,2 union all
  select 'b','b',1,2 union all
  select 'a','c',1,2 union all
  select 'b','b',1,3 union all
  select 'a','c',2,1        
)
  select col1, col2, col3, max(col4) as col4
    from tab
   group by col1, col2, col3;

col1  col2  col3  col4
  a     b    1     2
  a     c    1     2
  a     c    2     1
  b     b    1     3
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/LUI75731)

Comment: While yours is the basic, simplest, and best approach, I just need to remind you with `ROW_NUMBER()` approach as well. It'll be nicer to have an alternative approaches as well (just for references).

Comment: @iSR5 yes, that works for some situations mostly `row_number` used with a subquery. Thanks.

Comment: @iSR5 -- row number is used when the other columns (col1, col2, col3 in this case) are not the same.  eg return values of person with max salary in the same dept number.  row_number() makes no sense here.